# Powershell Parsing a .log file from a list of error codes located in a .txt file

Tags: powershell

I have a script that pulls a list of .log files from machines and saves them to a share. I'm trying to write a powershell script that will parse a .txt file of error codes then look for them in the log files. this is what I have so far:

```
Param(
  [Parameter (Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Enter full original file name (ex: HYPERLINK "C:\MyFiles\MyFile.log)"\\*\blahblah.log)")][string]$FilePath
  $a = Get-Content "Problem_codes.txt"
  foreach ($i in $a)
  {$i}
  )
(Select-String -Pattern $a -Path $FilePath).Count
```

If I do `(Select-String -Pattern 0x00080b -Path $FilePath).Count` it seems to work, when I try to read from the file it barfs:

```
Select-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is null.
At line:1 char:25
+ (Select-String -Pattern $a -Path $FilePath).Count
+                         ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be Select-String -Pattern $i  ?

Comment: Yup, you are correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ISE or PowerGui to write your code (syntax colorisation, matcing parenthesis Etc... ). Here is something where I try to change your code to be correct PowerShell, but I don't try it ...

```
Param([Parameter (Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Enter full original file name (ex: HYPERLINK `"C:\MyFiles\MyFile.log)`"\\*\blahblah.log)")][string]$FilePath)

$a = Get-Content "Problem_codes.txt"
foreach ($i in $a)
{
  $i
 (Select-String -Pattern $i -Path $FilePath).Count
}
```

Comment: thank you!, it was a lot clearer when using ISE. This also did the trick after I changed -Pattern $a to -Pattern $i as per the other suggest.